# Product Not showing In magento Frontend 1.6

Tags: magento

I have installed magento 1.6 on Ubuntu 10.4 server ,after installing i have added product from backend ,but
the product are no showing in frontend ,i haven,t installed the sample data which is there on magento site ,i have also clear magento cache, reindex the data but all in vain,Please help me out of this mess!!!!

Comment: :have you try to search products in search form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your product **in stock**

admin->catalog->manage products->your specific product->inventory

here change
**Qty** more than zero

make **stock Availability** in stock

Let me know is that helps